# .it domain, Dreamhost Hosting

Tags: domain-name-system, godaddy, dreamhost

I registered a .it domain name from GoDaddy, but I would like to host it with DreamHost.

I'm having problems. I can't change the nameservers to ns1.dreamhost.com (ns2, etc) I get this error message:

> Your changes could not be submitted. 1
>   change could not be submitted.
>
> The nameservers entered encountered
>   errors.

Other people have had this problem:
[1](http://discussion.dreamhost.com/thread-99926.html)
[2](http://discussion.dreamhost.com/thread-127269-post-129601.html#pid129601)

I could not find a clear, well explained solution.

User davethewave apparently solved the problem, but I don't understand how:

> **RE: Has anyone successfully hosted a .it site here?** hi i've two domains
>   .it here: http:/ /www.davethewave.it
>   and http:/ /www.hctrieste.it note that
>   the italian NIC does not allow to have
>   authoritative dns out of italy.  so
>   you have to modify dns manually, by
>   copying ip values from DH wep panel.
>   bye DaVe

So, perhaps I won't be able to use DreamHost DNS, and that's less than ideal, but I need this domain to work somehow.

When someone types in my .it url, I want them to see my DreamHost hosted site. How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Going by what "davethewave" said The restriction is only on the Authoritative Nameserver being in Italy and not where the webserver (non-authoritative DNS) servers are located

Find a Company which provides DNS services, specially supporting **.it** domains and use their DNS services.Once you/they configure your domain then you can have entries pointing to your Dreamhost server.

So your Authoritative DNS server will be in Italy and webserver on dreamhost or anywhere else where you want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to change the set of nameservers, but the address they are pointing to. Change the preset A, MX etc. records (or set some) to your new IP, to get rid of this.